# Convert IIS Proxy Rewrite to Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, reverse-proxy

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.6/{R:1}" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The concept is I have a server that accepts 80 & 443 requests and it redirects them to the appropriate server in the network.

My attempt:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    "/"
RewriteRule    "^/(.*)$"  “/“  [R=1]
ProxyPassReverse “/“ "http://192.168.1.6/“
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pet peeve, as an administrator you have access to the main apache configuration file and you should not rely on `.htaccess` files. Quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) files:

> You should **avoid using `.htaccess` files completely** *if you have access to httpd main server config* file. Using **`.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server**. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in the main Apache configuration file(s), as it will have the same effect with better performance.
>   ...
>   Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many respects, in the main server configuration.

In Apache I would configure a reverse proxy with the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive, rather than with mod_rewrite directives and set something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.6/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.6/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You Sir worth thousands of Kudos! Your first paragraph gave me food for thought to do exactly what I wanted to do but it just did not crossed my mind.